# How do I place a Python 3 file in the home folder of my Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Hey I created some python files on Windows and would now like to run those files on my Raspberry Pi. I've installed Python 3 on the Raspberry Pi, and placed the python file on the SD card. When I go to the Python 3.7.3 Shell and go to File->Open and type the name of my python file, it says the file does not exist. Is there a specific folder I have to place the python file in on the SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can place your files in some specific location of the SD and then access them from within the RasPi OS. I would recommend you to use a USB stick and copy the files that way. Handling USB is also easier and is possible wihtout rebooting the RasPi all the time.

Alternatively, you could establish an SFTP connection, when you are in the same wifi network or by connecting via ethernet. Here is a guide how you can transfer data via SCP, SFTP or Samba.
https://howchoo.com/pi/how-to-transfer-files-to-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: good call on the USB stick, it works and its more practical than constantly switching out the SD card

Answer (score 0):

/home/pi
This is where I usually put my files. What OS version did you install on the Pi? Python3 is usually part of the OS install.

Comment: I installed the Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) from the raspberry pi imager I downloaded from their website. It only had Geany and Thonny Python IDE under the programming tab before I installed Python 3 (IDLE). Super old raspberry pi I inherited, I don't know if that makes a difference.